# Unhandled Exception while running poisson reconstruction function

Tags: c++, cgal

While running poisson reconstruction function, it says unhandled exception (

> Unhandled exception at 0x6AEEF312 (libgmp-10.dll) in
>   poisson_reconstruction_example.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation
>   reading location 0x00FE3BBB.). ( visual studio 2013

)

I tried debugging , and i found this CGAL::make_surface_mesh(c2t3,surface,criteria,CGAL::Manifold_with_boundary_tag());

Here is the link :

https://justpaste.it/6g59w

This is provided example of CGAL library ( CGAL\examples\Poisson_surface_reconstruction_3 )

Expected result would be a triangular mesh.

Comment: make_surface_mesh () is producing exception

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer to. Please edit it to specify the version of CGAL that was used. And recompile your code in Debug, so that you can give us a backtrace of the issue. And probably in Debug, there will be CGAL assertion triggered, instead of that segfault.

Comment: I said: "recompile your code in Debug". Then run again. That should give you a backktrace of the erreur. The error is probably not in libgmp, but in the code calling it.